# Keeping AWS user data in sync across multiple Launch Configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I've got 7 apps, each with an auto scaling group and Launch Configuration for prod and dev, so 14 different launch configs all with the same User Data pasted into them, basically:

```
#cloud-config
users:
 - make a user
 - make another user

timezone: US/Eastern

package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
package_reboot_if_required: true
packages:
    - vim
```

now say I want to add another package, epel-release, I would need to go duplicate each of the 14 launch configurations, paste in the modified userdata, and associate the new LC with each of the 14 auto scaling groups.

I must be missing something, there's got to be an easier way to manage this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to manage this.
Take out the cloud config from the user data (and store it as a file in S3 for example) and just reference it in the user data via a **#include** directive.

You would need to update the launch configs once and after that each time you update it the instances, when launched will pick it up.

See:
http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/format.html#include-file

If you need more flexibility you could deploy the file with the image and have the cloud-init script reach to a local file via the init mechanism.

Bottom-line: the key is to pull out [most] of the config from the user data and just have a pointer to the config inside the user data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah that is very handy thanks. Originally I was trying to avoid the "slew of gold master AMIs" problem, but now I'm thinking anything I need in the cloud-init code maybe I should just roll into a spartan AMI.